# How to create an Angularjs controller within a meteor app?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm working in a meteor app project and I would like to integrate angularjs, I'm using urigo:ngmeteor to avoid conflict between these two frameworks, this is my code so far

```
//[root]/app.html
<body>
<div id="mybody" ng-app="store">
    <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <h1>Product Name: [[store.name]]</h1>
        <h1>Product Price: $[[store.price]]</h1>
        <p>Product Description: [[store.description]]</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

//[root]/client/js/app/js
   (function(){
       var app = angular.module('store', [], function(){ });
       var gem = {
           name: 'Dodecahendro',
           price: 2.95,
           description: '...'
       };
       console.log($("#mybody").length);
       app.controller('StoreController', function($scope){
           $scope.product = gem;
       });
    })();
```

but when I run it, I got this error message:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'StoreController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

and for the console.log() output I got 0

so, the question is, what am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same issue when deploying in production. I read a note somewhere about dependency injection and meteor uglify method potential conflicts, but can't find it anymore. I think tt's related to the name mangling in meteor (I guess) or your controller file isn't loaded. My project works perfectly in development.